# bash exec multi lines commands from files

Tags: bash, shell, exec

I want to `exec` multi lines commands from file.
Two files, one is `start.sh`, the other is `project_start.sh`.

file `start.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

# ...

# run project_start.sh and want to replace the current process.
exec $(cat project_start.sh) &

# ...
```

file `project_start.sh`

```
gunicorn --worker-class=tornado main:app -b 0.0.0.0:19991 --pid=/var/run/tool_mqtt/tool_mqtt.pid --access-logfile=/var/log/tool_mqtt/tool_mqtt.log --error-logfile=/var/log/tool_mqtt/tool_mqtt.log &
python main.py &
```

When I run `sh start.sh`, it's always shows

```
+ exec gunicorn --worker-class=tornado main:app -b 0.0.0.0:19991 --pid=/var/run/tool_mqtt/tool_mqtt.pid --access-logfile=/var/log/tool_mqtt/tool_mqtt.log --error-logfile=/var/log/tool_mqtt/tool_mqtt.log & python main.py &
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: & python main.py &
```

It shows the second line command is the arguments of the first line command. I use `\` after first line and it does not work.

How to avoid it?

Comment: I have to use `exec` for I need to use `wait` later.

Comment: `exec foo` does not allow you to use `wait`. It is means "exit my script and run this instead", somewhat equivalent to `foo; exit;`. You don't explain what you're trying to achieve but I'm pretty sure `exec` should have no part in it.

Comment: @thatotherguy you can use `pstree -p` to check if they are equivalent. Without `exec`, the `foo` run a non stopping script(running your project) within a new shell.

Comment: I ran `exec sleep 10 & wait` vs `sleep 10 & wait` and `pstree` showed the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you are seeing is that $( ) will execute the command, but the results are concatenated together in a single line.  To prove this to yourself, simple try this:

```
echo $( cat project_start.sh )
```

And so you can see that the second command in that file is simply passed as arguments to the first.

However, if you want to execute each line in that file separately consider writing a loop like this:

```
while 
  read command
do
  exec $command &
done < project_start.sh
#eventually - you will probably want a wait somewhere
wait
```

Comment: Yes, now I try to put commands to several files and for loop files with regex and exec every file, and then I can use wait and worked well.

Comment: If it's working for you feel free to accept the answer ;) -- I won't mind :).

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the newline in `start.sh` that terminates the `gunicorn` command disappears when the unquoted parameter expansion  performs word-splitting. The other problem is that `exec` expects a single command and its arguments, not arbitrary shell.

Just use `exec project_start.sh &` or `bash project_start.sh &`.

Comment: When I use `exec project_start.sh &`, it results in `start.sh: 146: exec: project_start.sh: not found`

Comment: `exec` uses path lookup, so you'll need `exec ./project_start.sh &` instead. Also, be sure that `project_start.sh` is actually executable if you use `exec` (`chmod +x project_start.sh`).

Comment: Why even have `exec`? `exec cmd &` makes no sense.

Comment: True; I left it in as a microoptimization in the case where `project_start.sh` is an "pure" executable, rather than a shell script, as it would save a fork. But since `project_start.sh` has to start a new shell the same as `bash project_start.sh`, it doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I have to use `exec` for `wait` only can wait its child process.

Comment: @chepner So I need to use exec to replace the current process, not to start a new shell.

Comment: @Simon The process `exec` would replace is the one forked by `&`; from the perspective of `start.sh`, it doesn't matter much which you use.